# Keras Model gets high accuracy in training and validation then messes up on Confusion metric

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I have a binary classification model that get really good scores in the training validation and testing phases.

```
validation_generator.reset # reset the validation gen for testing
loss: 0.0725 - accuracy: 0.9750 - val_loss: 0.1703 - val_accuracy: 0.9328
scores = model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False, verbose=1)
print(scores)
[0.023366881534457207, 0.9353214502334595]
```

Ok, so that looks really good to me, correct? 
Now when I try the confusion metrics this all gets grouped over to one class which is totally wrong.

```
Confusion Matrix
[[1045    0]
[1537    0]]
```

Here is the CM code:

```
validation_generator.reset
Y_pred = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, validation_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE+1)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
print(confusion_matrix(validation_generator.classes, y_pred))
target_names = ['male', 'female']
print(classification_report(validation_generator.classes, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

That should not be I dont think. It might be with the generators possibly but it looks correct to me.

```
BATCH_SIZE = 32
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
                               horizontal_flip=True,                            
                               validation_split=0.2) # set validation split

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    DATA_PATH,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode='binary',
    subset='training') # set as training data

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    DATA_PATH, # same directory as training data
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    shuffle=False,
    class_mode='binary',
    subset='validation') # set as validation data
```

Should I set the validation batch size to 1?

Here is the model declaration if that helps.

```
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE,
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs = EPOCHS,
    verbose=1, 
    callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

**UPDATE AND FIX FOR THIS PROBLEM:**

Add this to the code

```
y_pred[y_pred <= 0.5] = 0.
y_pred[y_pred > 0.5] = 1.
#Old code
#y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1) # This does not work for this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you are doing a *binary* classification and I see in your code that you are using `np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)`. I think argmax should be used with multiple class classification.

For solution, you should try something like `y_pred = [y[0] >=  0.5 for y in y_pred]`

Note that I'm not sure about this code works **exactly** or not but I'm sure that `np.argmax()` need to replaced.

Comment: Yep, that did it thank you. I put the exact fix in my edits. I appreciate you setting me stright on this.